# Responsive dashboard using jQuery & Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, dashboard, portal

I'm trying to create a portal/dashboard using jQuery & Bootstrap. I need the ability to display gadgets with fixed dimensions that can be displayed on the same page together. I am giving the user the ability to define a template for each page, which defines the dimensions of gadgets that can be displayed on the page and also their layout.

I can already do a basic non-responsive dashboard but the part that is confusing me, is that I want to make the dashboard responsive. This would be fairly easy if gadgets were all of similar sizes, organised into rows, as per Bootstrap's grid system.

I guess the best example is this screenshot I found online.

[image: Dashboard example]

The first gadget spans two rows and the next two only span one. I can't see how to do this using Bootstrap's grid system.

Alternatively, should it even be responsive? Is it a better user experience if the dashboard isn't responsive?

Edit: I do have clients who use tablets and/or cellphones.

Comment: Just for information, I also created a simple dashboard using http://gridster.net/ and I'm looking at http://masonry.desandro.com/ to see if I could ignore the responsive side and use an existing library to provide a professional dashboard. Thanks all.

Comment: I thought I'd return and post an update. This design didn't suit my needs so I designed the dashboard to let users resize and move gadgets. I guess the net result is not really a true dashboard but it works nicely as users can create separate pages for desktops, phones and tablets. The dashboard no longer uses a template for specifying a page layout. It was just too fiddly for my users. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Responsiveness is always a plus when you are working on a small screen. So if you have clients with small screens e.g. phones, tablets, old scool monitors, then yes, it is a good idea to be responsive.

For the grid system problem. Try to group widgets in such a way that they fit into a row. For example the table and the 2 pie-charts are perfect candidates to be in a single row. Then the pie-charts in their `<div class="col-xx-6">` tad should be in separate rows and so on.

You can nest as much rows as you want.

A row spans along all 12 columns of the parent. Therefore the table and the pie-charts should be in different `<div>`s to allow the content to "fall down" when there is no room for it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good starting point for you in [bootply](http://bootply.com). This is a dashboard that has been constructed using the bootstrap grid system. [Link Here](http://www.bootply.com/kbNQIMKs13) You can add responsiveness to the chart controls by using [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) which are quite popular amoung front end developers.